# Evaluating a statement without calculating the indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

I'm cramming for a supplementary exam so you might see a ton of questions like these in the 48+ hours to come <3

The question is more of just a yes or no ; Evaluate the statement without calculating the indefinite integral.

$$ \int \frac{2x+1}{x+1} \,\mathrm dx = 2x -\ln|x+1| + C$$

1.) Seeing as how I'm not allowed to calculate the indefinite integral I assume I should work backwards using it. ie

$${{d} \over {dx}} (2x - \ln|x+1| + C)$$

2.) The hell am I supposed to do with $\ln|x+1|$, I have this tendency to split the page and answer the question due to $|x+1|$ having two possible answers.

That being said all I did was assume that $|x+1|$ would be $(x+1)$ and not $-(x+1)$. The result was :

$${2x+1} \over {x+1}$$

Does that answer the question? How would I go about showing my assumptions?

Oh and unrelated/related , I can do the above because of the fundamental theorem of calculus right?

Comment: If you are not allowed to integrate to verify the statement (the anti derivative is indeed correct), then are you allowed to take the derivative of the right hand side? That way you can also verify the statement. The derivative of $ln|x+1|$ is $\frac{1}{x+1}$ I assume you can use that piece of information?

Comment: Our lecturer is on vacation so I can't really ask her ^-^ We didn't get a memo for the paper either. So I'm playing a pretty dangerous game.

Comment: Well, there are only two ways (as far as I know). Either you integrate the left hand side to arrive at the right hand side or you differentiate the right hand side to get to the left hand side. There is nothing else to it. The integral problem is easy...

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was thinking too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know that $\dfrac d{dx}\ln|x|= \dfrac 1 x$.

To see that that is true, first do it piecewise: for $x>0$, and then for $x<0$.  If $x<0$ then you have $\ln(-x)$, and $-x$ is positive, and you use the chain rule.  Once you have done this just once, then remember it for use on subsequent occasions such as the exercise that you quote in your posted question.

Your technique is otherwise just what the person who posed the question probably expects.

There is one slight subtlety: The "constant" $C$ should be **piecewise** constant, i.e. one constant on the interval $x>-1$ and a possibly different constant on the interval $x<-1$, because there is a gap in the domain at $-1$.

Comment: I have this huge wall behind me full of rules and formulas , somehow this one eluded me. Thanks!

Comment: @ArmandConnorDuPlooy : Notice the proper way to code $a\ln b$ or $a\ln(b)$.  It's a\ln b or a\ln(b).  The backslash does NOT ONLY prevent italicization, but also results in proper spacing.  Notice that the spacing to the right of $\ln$ is different in the two expressions; so the spacing conventions are built in to the software. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

1) Differentiation is definitely the way to go

2) Recall that $\int \frac{1}{x+1} dx = \ln|x+1|$...  Therefore,  the absolute value goes away when you differentiation,  implying that $\frac{d}{dx}  \ln|x+1| = \frac{1}{x+1}$